# Alternative to Dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

**Getting an error:** on line  `CurrentFilters.Add($"Colors", Colors[i].ToString());`

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: Colors
```

**Issue:** If `Dictionary` can't have same key than what are my alternatives? I found few on Google like putting into a `List` but they don't work with `asp-all-route-data`.

Also since, it is auto Bind; this mean I can't do something like `CurrentFilters.Add($"Colors[i]", Colors[i].ToString());` this will work but it wont bind bc name `"Colors[1]"` is not same as `"Colors"`.

If you click on `<a>` tag than it will send URL format: `localhost234/Index?SearchString=text%Colors=red&Colors=blue&SortOrder=Colors_asc`

back-end code

```
[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public Dictionary<string, string> CurrentFilters { get; set; }

[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public List<string>? Colors { get; set; } //list of colors user selects
public SelectList? Colors_SELECT { get; set; } //fill dropdownlist with colors values

 public async Task OnGetAsync()
 {
     Colors_SELECT = getColors(); //fill dropdown with all colors 
    
     //this fill get back into asp-all-route-data
     CurrentFilters.Clear();
     CurrentFilters.Add("SearchString", SearchString);
     for (int i = 0; i < Colors.Count; i++)
     {
          // ISSUE is here
          CurrentFilters.Add($"Colors", Colors[i]);
     }
  }
```

Front-End - form has many different filters for my grid-table

```
<form asp-page="./index" method="get">
     <input type="text" asp-for="SearchString" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." />
     <select asp-for="Colors" asp-items="@Model.Colors_SELECT" class="MultiSelect" multiple>...</select>
      ...
</form>
```

grid-table - display data from database. Header links are for filtering and sorting. `asp-all-route-data` has different filters inside that get pass to URL

```
<Table>
  ...  // header hyper link
  <a  asp-page="./Index" method="get" 
      asp-all-route-data="@Model.CurrentFilters" 
      asp-route-SortOrder="@Model.Colors_Sort" >
              @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MyList[0].Colors)
     </a>
...
```

**Update:** I tried using list inside Dictionary but it gives an error.

```
[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public Dictionary<string, List<string>> CurrentFilters { get; set; }
```

Error:

```
Error: 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,
 System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>' to 
'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, string>'. 
 An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Comment: Use a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`? Or use something other than `asp-all-route-data`...

Comment: You haven't provided any information on what you intend to do with `CurrentFilters`. What result do you expect from `CurrentFilters["Colors"]`? How will it be used?

Comment: BTW, why do you have `Colors[i].ToString()`? You know `Colors` type is `List<string>` so the type of `Colors[i]` is `string` already. Why are you doing `$"Colors"` when you are not interpolating any values?

Comment: I tried using `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` but it gives the same casting error

Comment: `CurrentFilters.Add($"Colors", Colors[i].ToString())` is nonsensical; you're using a hard-coded string for the key, so it can never be used to distinguish between values. Why do you use a `Dictionary`? Use a `List<string>`.

Comment: sorry i am bit confoused. I started razor recently. so `Colors[i]` is already a `List<string>` and it has list of colors that user has selected from form. depending on user choice, `colors[i]` will have different values. I think I am mis understanding

Comment: I am using `Dictionary` to bind all my filters with `asp-route-all-data`. However `Dictionary` doesnt allow multi keys. I am using `asp-route-all-data` bc i have many different filters inside form (other than Colors). so sending all together makes sense; Rather than adding `asp-route` on every column `<a>` for each filter. for example: if there are 10 filters (colors, shapes, locations etc..) than each column will have 10 `asp-route` etc... I search all result on google for last few days but unable fix it

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public Dictionary<string, List<string>> CurrentFilters { get; set; }
```

instead of  `public Dictionary<string, string> CurrentFilters { get; set; }`

To handle this in your `OnGetAsync` handler do something like this:

```
public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    CurrentFilters.Clear();
    CurrentFilters.Add("SearchString", new List<string>());
    CurrentFilters["SearchString"].Add(SearchString);

    CurrentFilters.Add($"Colors", new List<string>());
    for (int i = 0; i < Colors.Count; i++)
    {
        CurrentFilters[$"Colors"].Add(Colors[i].ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using but it always gives me the same error: `Dicitionary<string, List<string>> CurrentFilter cannot implicitly convert type system.collections.generic.Dictionary<string, System.Collections.Generic.List<string>> to System.collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, string>. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: @dave This is because 'asp-all-route-data' expects an 'IDictionary<string,string>'. So try finding something other than 'asp-all-route-data' or do something like 'CurrentFilters.Add($"Colors_{Colors[i]}", Colors[i])'

Comment: btw: can you explain how and where you use the values collected with 'CurrentFilters'?

Comment: If I use `CurrentFilters.Add($"Colors_{Colors[i]}", Colors[i]`, than it wont bind to `<select asp-for="Colors"` bc bind name is not same anymore. I feel like my lack of knowledge of razor page is limiting my options as to how to do this

Comment: i dont have to use `CurrentFilters.Add($"Colors_{Colors[i]}", Colors[i])`. I just dont know any other way. `CurrentFilters` has `Bind` property to `asp-all-route-data`; so if you click on `<a>` tag than it will auto send all `CurrentFilters`  values to URL ex: `localhost234/Index?SearchString=text%Colors=red&Colors=blue&SortOrder=Colors_asc` etc.