# How to pass multi List values using <a> tag?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

[Basic example link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-7.0) - following link is what I am trying to build. But this is only for single value.

**Issue Detail**  After I select multi `colors` in `<select>`, Then i click `<a>` tag, I want to pass the value of what i select in `<select>`. Currently after clicking on `<a>` tag, it wont keep values selcted inside `<select>`

**Step#1** Here I am creating Form with 2 filters. 1 search text box and 2 selectlist

```
<form asp-page="./index" method="get">
     <input type="text" asp-for="SearchString"  />
     <select asp-for="Colors" asp-items="@Model.Colors_SELECT" class="MultiSelect" multiple>...</select>
   ...
</form>
```

**Step#2** Display data in table grid. `<a>` is passing filters to url

```
<table>
....
     <a asp-page="./My_Training"   
                    asp-route-SearchString="@Model.SearchString"
                    asp-route-Colors="@Model.Colors"
                    asp-route-SortOrder="@Model.Colors_Sort">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MyListData[0].Colors)
     </a>
     .. // more `<a>` tags. 1 for each column 
  </table>
```

**Step#3** Back-end code: - mainly bind filter values

```
[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public string? SearchString { get; set; }
[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public List<string>? Colors { get; set; }
public SelectList? Colors_SELECT { get; set; }

public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    // everything is auto bind to properties  
}
```

**What I tried:** according to google, they recommended using `asp-all-route-data` with `Dictionary`. I have tried this code and it doesnt work for multi values. `Dictionary` doesnt allow same key. for example: if I use `asp-all-route-data` and pass URL like `Colors[0]=Red&Colors[1]=Green` than it wont keep values selected inside `<select>`

**I also Tried** to do this. This works but the code is a mess and hard to maintain if you have too many filters & columns in data grid

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="URL_String" />
...
<a href="/Index? @Model.URL_String&SortOrder=@Model.Colors_Sort">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CourseTakenList[0].Colors)
</a>

public string? URL_String { get; set; } = "";

  public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        string? createURL = "?";
        createURL += $"SearchString={SearchString}&";
        foreach (var p in Colors)
        {
            createURL += $"Colors={p}&";
        }

        if (createURL.EndsWith("?") || createURL.EndsWith("&"))
        {
            createURL = createURL.TrimEnd(createURL[createURL.Length - 1]); //remove last '&' 
        }

        string url = $"{HttpContext.Request.Path}{createURL}";
        return Redirect(url);
    } 

  public async Task OnGetAsync()
  {
        URL_String = Request.QueryString.ToString().Replace("??", "?");
        CurrentSort = Request.Query["SortOrder"];        
 }
```

Comment: Can you also add what you actually want to see as result? (It makes no sense to have collection of urls in *a single* href attribute of A)

Comment: I will update my post shortly. For single values like StringString, it works fine but for multi-select values (Colors), it doesnt. I am just trying to add multi-select filters to my table-grid. It doesnt matter how just trying to make it work. here is a example that I am following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Please don't re-ask the same question again [Alternative to Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75076373/alternative-to-dictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `asp-all-route-data` can't pass value with the same key, So you need to add index by yourself, Please refer to this simple demo:

```
@{
    var colors = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    var i = 0;
    foreach (var item in Model.colors)
    {
        colors.Add($"colors[{i}]", item);
        i++;
    }
}

<a asp-page="index" asp-all-route-data="colors">Test</a>
```

It will pass data like:

`?colors[0]=red&colors[1]=green&colors[2]=black`

Demo:

[image]

**=========================Update================**

```
<select multiple id="selectone">
    <option value="red">red</option>  
    <option value="black">black</option>
    <option value="white">white</option>  
    <option value="yellow">yellow</option>  
     
</select>

<button onclick="MySelect()">Select color</button>



<a asp-page="index" asp-route-SearchString="Test" id="color">Test</a>



<script>
   
    

    function MySelect(){
        var result = document.getElementById("selectone").selectedOptions;
        var arr=[];
        for(let i=0,len = result.length;i<len;i++){
            if(result[i].selected){
                arr.push("colors["+i+"]=" + result[i].value)
            }
            
        }


        var str=arr.join("&");
       var a = document.getElementById("color").getAttribute('href');

       var url = a+ "&" + str;

       document.getElementById("color").href = url;
       
        
    }


   
</script>
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: i understand But How it will Bind with `<select asp-for="Colors" ...>`?  If you click on `<form>` than it will select colors value in dropdownlist. But than if you click on `<a>` tag for sorting than it wont select values in dropdownlist bc `Colors[0]` isnt same as `Colors`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your point, Do you mean after i select colors in `<select>`, Then i click `<a>` tag, It will pass the value of what i select in `<select>`?

Comment: yes thats right. After you select colors in `<select>`, than click on `<a>` tag, I want to keep values selected in `<select>`. Current code will not select values inside `<select>` bc of different names i.e `Colors[0]` & `Colors`. Please let me know I can try to explain more. I just moved from old `web forms` in `.net framework` so this razor stuff seem so different

Comment: Do you accept to use jacascript to achieve it?

Comment: at this point, ill take whatever i can get. Sure!

Comment: Please check the answer i updated, after i select options in `select`, i use javascript to save the value into url.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251099/discussion-between-xinran-shen-and-dave).